# Why do my two tables fail to appear next to each other in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

My basic outline is this:

```
<div class="availability-tables" >
   <table class="table table-bordered availability-table-property-column">
   </table>
   <table class="table viewings-table show-scroll-bar" >
   </table>
</div>
```

More detail in the JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/3ezxu/8/

If you run it in IE9 (or IE9 compatibility mode with IE9 document mode in a later version of IE) then one of the tables appears underneath the other, instead of next to it.

In Chrome/FF/later versions of IE, the two tables appear next to each other with a scroll bar for the left hand table.

Floating left like so:

```
.gyms-table {
    float: left;
}
.availability-table-property-column {
    float:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3ezxu/9/

Just flat out doesn't work in any browser, and if I use absolute or relative positioning, then I can't get the the scroll-x to work

Any suggestions? I'm really at the end of my tether with this one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with tables is that even if you define a width, it is affected by the cells content. The table's width may not be respected.

Maybe you could wrap your tables with a div each, then use these divs to position side-by-side, like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/3ezxu/15/

```
<div class="availability-tables" >
  <div>
      <table class="table table-bordered availability-table-property-column">
         <!-- TABLE 01 -->          
      </table>
  </div>

  <div>
      <table class="table gyms-table show-scroll-bar" >
         <!-- TABLE 02 -->
      </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

And add this to css:

```
.availability-tables {
  padding-right: 7px;
  padding-left: 7px;
  display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.availability-tables > div {
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;
}

.availability-tables > div:first-child {
    width: 20%;
}
```

Comment: I might give that a go - but your jsfiddle has the title table really low down for some reason?

Comment: True... weird. Sorry I was testing only on IE9